# Cannot compile ERC-20 smart contract

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I'm having problems with compiling this controller smart contract.
It's throwing error at line 18:
address payable tokenSource = {tokenAddress};

Any idea what went wrong?

Thank you,
Valerie.

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^ 0.8.0;

interface IToken {
function totalSupply() external view returns(uint256);
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns(uint256);
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);

}

contract TestController{
event TokenPurchased(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount, uint256 _bnb);

```
IToken Token;

bool public is_preselling;
address payable owner;
address payable tokenSource = {tokenAddress};
address payable fundreceiver;
uint256 soldTokens;
uint256 receivedFunds;

constructor(IToken _tokenAddress)  {
    Token = _tokenAddress;
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
    fundreceiver = owner;
    is_preselling = true;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "invalid owner");
    _;
}

//buy tokens
function sale(uint256 _amount) public payable returns(bool)  {
    require(is_preselling, "pre selling is over.");
    Token.transferFrom(tokenSource, msg.sender, _amount);
    fundreceiver.transfer(msg.value);
    soldTokens += _amount;
    receivedFunds += msg.value;
    emit TokenPurchased(msg.sender, _amount, msg.value);
    return true;
}

function getTokenSupply() public view returns(uint256){
    return Token.totalSupply();
}

function getTokenbalance(address _address) public view returns(uint256){
    return Token.balanceOf(_address);
}

function totalSoldTokens() public view returns(uint256){
    return soldTokens;
}
function totalReceivedFunds() public view returns(uint256){
    return receivedFunds;
}

function getbalance()  public onlyOwner {
    owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
}


function SetReceiver(address payable _fund) public onlyOwner {
    fundreceiver = _fund;
}


function SetPreSellingStatus() public onlyOwner {
    if (is_preselling) {
        is_preselling = false;
    } else {
        is_preselling = true;
    }
}
```

**}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because `tokenAddress` is not defined.

- If you want to assign token address to `tokenSource` so you can assign in constructor.

**Try to run below given code may it will solve your issue.**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IToken { function totalSupply() external view returns(uint256); function balanceOf(address account) external view returns(uint256); function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);

}

contract TestController{ 

event TokenPurchased(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount, uint256 _bnb);

IToken Token;

bool public is_preselling;
address payable owner;
address payable tokenSource;
address payable fundreceiver;
uint256 soldTokens;
uint256 receivedFunds;

constructor(IToken _tokenAddress)  {
    tokenSource=payable(address(_tokenAddress));
    Token = _tokenAddress;
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
    fundreceiver = owner;
    is_preselling = true;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "invalid owner");
    _;
}

//buy tokens
function sale(uint256 _amount) public payable returns(bool)  {
    require(is_preselling, "pre selling is over.");
    Token.transferFrom(tokenSource, msg.sender, _amount);
    fundreceiver.transfer(msg.value);
    soldTokens += _amount;
    receivedFunds += msg.value;
    emit TokenPurchased(msg.sender, _amount, msg.value);
    return true;
}

function getTokenSupply() public view returns(uint256){
    return Token.totalSupply();
}

function getTokenbalance(address _address) public view returns(uint256){
    return Token.balanceOf(_address);
}

function totalSoldTokens() public view returns(uint256){
    return soldTokens;
}
function totalReceivedFunds() public view returns(uint256){
    return receivedFunds;
}

function getbalance()  public onlyOwner {
    owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
}


function SetReceiver(address payable _fund) public onlyOwner {
    fundreceiver = _fund;
}


function SetPreSellingStatus() public onlyOwner {
    if (is_preselling) {
        is_preselling = false;
    } else {
        is_preselling = true;
    }
}
}
```